# trying to calculate peak average response time for a day? Can this be done in a sql statemen or do I need to use a stored procedure?

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services

looking to get the peak average time for a response time, so far this is the query:

```
SELECT DATEPART(Year, TransactionDate) AS ReportYear
     , DATEPART(Month, TransactionDate) AS ReportMonth
     , DATEPART(wk, TransactionDate) AS ReportWeek
     , DATEPART(Day, TransactionDate) AS ReportDay
     , DATEPART(Hour, TransactionDate) AS ReportHour
     , ProcessName
     , ResponseTime
FROM PerformanceLog
GROUP BY    ProcessName
          , DATEPART(Year, TransactionDate)
          , DATEPART(Month, TransactionDate)
          , DATEPART(wk, TransactionDate)
          , DATEPART(Day, TransactionDate)
          , DATEPART(Hour, TransactionDate)
          ,  ResponseTime
ORDER BY   ReportWeek, ReportDay, ProcessName, ReportHour, ResponseTime
```

Comment: What's wrong with what you've got so far?  What's your data look like and what's your desired output?

Comment: In other words max ReportHour response time per ReportDay per ProcessName

Comment: data looks like: TransactionDate: 2015-01-01 10:21:00:12 ProcessName: "Api1", Response time in milliseconds: 12342

Comment: which db are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The query below will return the maximum response time per hour per process name. If you want to include ties, use `rank()` instead of `row_number()`.

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT DATEPART(Year, TransactionDate) AS ReportYear
        , DATEPART(Month, TransactionDate) AS ReportMonth
        , DATEPART(wk, TransactionDate) AS ReportWeek
        , DATEPART(Day, TransactionDate) AS ReportDay
        , DATEPART(Hour, TransactionDate) AS ReportHour
        , ProcessName
        , ResponseTime
        , row_number() over (partition by DATEPART(Year, TransactionDate)
            , DATEPART(Month, TransactionDate)
            , DATEPART(wk, TransactionDate)
            , DATEPART(Day, TransactionDate) 
            , DATEPART(Hour, TransactionDate)
            , ProcessName
            order by ResponseTime desc) rn
    FROM PerformanceLog
) t1 WHERE rn = 1
```